# Javascript - Back button history

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Single Page Application running in PhoneGap, and driving through content with Sammy.js

Consider this:

The home page is domain.com/#/panel
[image]

Then I click on Reglas(regulations)
The location.hash updates to #/regulations

[image]

After this I can see the current regulations, when I click anyone of this, I update again the location.hash to #/regulation/1 (or whatever number the regulation is):

[image]

**Here is the deal:**

I have a back button inside my app in the navbar next to the screen title, and it have a click listener with this:

```
$('back').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    // window.history.back();
    history.back();
});
```

It works well when I'm at the 2nd screen (#/regulations), it brings me back to #/panel. But when I'm on a 3rd screen (#/regulation/1) it brings again to #/panel instead of the #/regulations section.

**When I click browser's backbutton it works very good** but somehow when I click MY back button it doesn't work properly.

I have read some topics about this, like Mozilla's one:
[image]

Like Mozilla said, it should work exactly as if I clicked the browser's back button, but it doesn't.

I have tried with:

```
window.history.back();
    window.history.go(-1);
    history.back();
    history.go(-1);
```

It seems not working with anything.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check out pushState and popState : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: 1) try window.history.length; to see how many links you have in history when you are in 3rd screen !

Comment: 2) what happens if you try from 3rd screen history.go(-2) ?

Comment: I had grammar mistakes in my code. Thank you guys for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry little mistakes happens to anybody:

**e.preventDefault();** (parentheses)
and **#back** (sharp) were the problem.

However, if anybody get in this trouble, Mozilla had the reason, any of this lines **work exactly as if the user clicks browser's back button**:

```
$('#back').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
    // window.history.go(-1);
    // history.back();
    // history.go(-1);
});
```